# Example of pass by reference in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I can't really find resources on how pass-by-reference works in Prolog. I tested a program here to show the addresses of the variables but I think instantiation is a must in prolog.

```
 test(Z):-
    write(Z).
 main:-
    X,
    test(X).
```

Is there a way to make this code work? to show a pass-by-reference in Prolog.

Comment: Where did you get the `pass-by-reference` idea working with Prolog from?

Comment: I remember trying to write a code as well before (with prolog) and it printed out an address instead of the value instead but I can't replicate this since I was not able to save the file. Aren't predicates in Prolog pass-by-reference in nature?

Comment: Every time you say `pass-by-reference` I think, either, this person is so off the norm for Prolog that this makes no sense, or this person is so deep into the language theory I will have to get my references out to check this. But I also think neither of them is the right idea which is why I am asking.

Comment: Can you give an example of expected input and expected output without noting `pass-by-reference` and then it might make more sense. Your comment was helpful but did not nail it down enough for me to answer.

Comment: I made a minor edit to the code (changed X to Z from 'test()'). What I want to show is that the variable Z would also take the address of X from main. If, for example, the address of X is 2500 and the address of Z is 2000, after calling test(Z), both would have the address of 2500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment

`both would have the address of 2500.`

What you describe is actually the unification of two different variables that are then unified.

---

Example

```
?- format('~w,~w~n',[X,Y]),X=Y,format('~w,~w~n',[X,Y]).
_11326,_11332
_11326,_11326
X = Y.
```

Notice that before the unification `X=Y`
that X has an address as you call it of `_11326` and Y has an address of `_11332` which are different

and that after the unification

that X has an address of `_11326` and Y has an address of `_11326` which are now the same.

---

**EDIT**

Here is your example code modified a bit to try and show what you seek but as it shows, it does not demonstrate the unification of two different variables.

```
check :-
    % X,  % This will cause an error because X is not bound to a callable predicate.
    format('X @1: ~w~n',[X]),
    test(X),
    format('X @4: ~w~n',[X]),
    true.

check(X) :-
    format('X @1: ~w~n',[X]),
    test(X),
    format('X @4: ~w~n',[X]),
    true.

test(Z):-
    format('Z @2: ~w~n',[Z]),
    write(Z),
    format('~nZ @3: ~w~n',[Z]),
    true.
```

Example run

```
?- check.
X @1: _8372
Z @2: _8372
_8372
Z @3: _8372
X @4: _8372
true.

?- check(A).
X @1: _9446
Z @2: _9446
_9446
Z @3: _9446
X @4: _9446
true.
```

In other words, I don't think you would have found your answer from the example code you stated using.

---

**EDIT**

Example using SWI-Prolog and trace/0 to see a variable being passed, unified with another variable and returning with with a different address than starting. trace/0 has the advantage that it will show the address of the variable without having to access the variable, E.g. format/2.

Note: Both of the example code below use X as singleton variable. This is expected to give a compile warning. Do not fix as that is expected and desired.

Code

```
check_1(Y) :-
    test_1(X,Y).

test_1(X,Y) :-
    X = Y.
```

Example run

```
?- visible(+all).

?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- check_1(A).
   Call: (10) example:check_1(_101582) ? creep
   Unify: (10) example:check_1(_101582)
   Call: (11) example:test_1(_103590, _101582) ? creep
   Unify: (11) example:test_1(_104356, _101582)
   Call: (12) _105066=_101582 ? creep
   Exit: (12) _101582=_101582 ? creep
   Exit: (11) example:test_1(_101582, _101582) ? creep
   Exit: (10) example:check_1(_101582) ? creep
true.
```

Walking the trace and understanding it is left as an exercise. If one needs to ask a question about this start a new question, don't ask here as this question has an accepted answer.

Another code example.

```
check_2(Y) :-
    test_2(X,Y).

test_2(X,X).
```

Again this one is left as an exercise.

Comment: These are not addresses. You keep on using this word but it is _very_ forced in the context of Prolog. At best, you could claim that the variable _name_ is an address, but I don't see the value of such acrobatics. Sadly giving you a minus vote because of it.

Comment: @TA_intern I did not pick that terminology the OP did. I also noted `address as you call it` in the answer but only the first few times.

Comment: two wrongs don't make a right and so on. Those numbers you see there are automatically assigned names at best. They happen to have numbers in them, but this is an artifact of how the implementation you are using is assigning those names. Those are NOT addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Define a predicate that has a single "output variable" and set it in the predicate:

```
my_predicate(5). % sets the variable to 5
```

Now call it:

```
?- my_predicate(X).
X = 5.
```

Great, it works.

---

Now **forget about** *pass-by-value*, *pass-by-reference*, and even more so, variable *addresses*. This is not correct terminology when you talk about Prolog. You have logical variables, variable instantiation, unification, immutability and so on.

Comment: This ^^^ — Prolog is... different.